# From SQL records to Python binarizer

Tags: python, nlp

I am new to python and I need to get these results from SQL database.

This is how my data look like in the database

Features List X

```
Group Type Code Frequency
1     A    A1   3
1     A    A2   6
1     A    A3   2
1     B    B1   9
1     B    B2   4
2     A    A1   5
2     A    A4   7
2     B    B1   2
2     B    B2   1
2     C    C1   7
...
```

Results List
Y

```
Group Result
1     P938
1     H266
1     J992
2     F882
2     K391
```

these are in SQL Server database

My target to get these into python code where I can use predictive modelling like this

```
Group A1 A2 A3 A4 ... A383 B1 B2 ... B93838 C1 .. C3838 ... 
1     3  6  2  7      1    9  4      8      1     4
2     2  1  5  7      2    8  2      6      2     6
.
.
.
```

The header is going to be the values from the Features List X
and the values are the frequency in X

while the results are going to be array

```
Group Results
1     [0,1,0,0,1,..,1]
2     [1,0,1,0,1,..,0]
```

> ***Edit***

My result will should be in a single row array

Example

```
Group Result
1     B
1     D
1     E
2     A
2     B
2     C
2     E
3     C
3     F
4     B
4     E
```

I need the result to be an array that has the binary of columns
**A,B,C,D,E,F**

```
Group ResultArray
1     [0,1,0,1,1,0]
2     [1,1,1,0,1,0]
3     [0,0,1,0,0,1]
4     [0,1,0,0,1,0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using Pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
```

it should go something along these lines:

1. get your data into a pandas DataFrame, either by downloading it to a file and loading it:

   ```
   df = pd.read_csv(<file_name>)
   ```

   or if you have a direct connection:

   ```
   df = pd.read_sql(<query>, <connection>)
   ```
2. for the features use Pivot:

   ```
   features_df = df.pivot(index='Group', columns='Code', values='Frequency')
   ```
3. for the results use groupby:

   ```
   results_df = df.groupby('Group').apply(lambda row: row.values[0])
   ```
4. merge/join the 2 dataframes:

   ```
    pd.merge(features_df, results_df)
   ```

Comment: The features_df works exactly as i needed thx for that, but for the result probably i did not explained it correctly.. I will edit my question

Comment: don't understand, what role does "P938" play?